# Is it possible to support orafce in google postgres cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql, orafce

we used orafce for our oracle to postgres migration, it work very well.
https://github.com/orafce.
Recently we try to migrate to cloud db, we choose the google cloud, however, I found that the google cloud is not support the orafce extension.
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions#postgresql-extensions-supported-by-cloud-sql

Is it possible to support orafce extension in google cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment “orafce” extension **is not supported.**

As you can see on this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/151509548), many other users of Cloud SQL wish for this, I would recommend you to “star” or +1 this public issue in order to show your interest for this feature and by +1 it you will be updated for any changes on the implementation of this feature.

Comment: Please accept my answer for better visibility for the comunity.